# How they announce a flight at the airport?

Tags: numbers

I want to know how they announce a flight at the airport, for example:

> Lufthansa Flug 375

Do they announce the flight number like normal numbers or digit by digit?

Comment: International flights will always be announced in English too.

Comment: @Takkat: I see, but I wanted to understand the German version.

Comment: Who is "they"? <!--Comments must be at least 15 characters in length.-->

Comment: completely off-topic: Lufthansa flight 357 is [actually a train](http://www.vvs.de/download/StuttgartAb.pdf) (search for "LH 357")

Comment: ...and so is LH 375 ;-)

Comment: @Jan: Oh? But it was in a German book and the part about flight announcements!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no fixed rule for this. I've heard all possible versions:

- "Achtung meine Damen und Herren, Lufthansa Flug Drei - Fünfundsiebzig ..."
- "Achtung meine Damen und Herren, Lufthansa Flug Dreihundertfünfundsiebzig ..."
- "Achtung meine Damen und Herren, Lufthansa Flug Drei - Sieben - Fünf ..."

None of these seems to be "right" or "wrong" and you'll find them all.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think flight numbers are normally announced digit by digit.

There are some examples on this site: http://www.light2art.de/mp3-Flughafen-Ansagen.html (listen to "Köln: letzter Aufruf nach Palma de Mallorca")

Comment: For me the links on light2art did not play ;)